# Regex to match file extension but allow query paramters

Tags: regex

What would be a good regex to match file extensions when grepping a log file.  But the file may have query paramters.

For example to match css files i can easily do the following:

```
(.css)$
```

But what if the file name was showing in the log as:

the-file.css?08122013

Or any other random string on the end?

Comment: .+(.css).+$ would match anything then .css then anything... But I assume you already knew that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this?  `(\.css)(?:\?.+)?$`

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following.

```
(\.[^.]*)$
```

See [`Live demo`](http://regex101.com/r/tZ5iV2)

**Note**: If it seems to match more than expected use `?` for a non greedy match.